# How to update version when only dependencies are updated?

Tags: release-management, semantic-versioning, software-updates

I have a public project that I'm the single developer. I love updating packages to new versions regularly and keep the project up to date with the updated environment. This is probably not always a good approach as discussed [in this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225217/when-would-you-choose-not-to-update-a-third-party-library-to-a-newer-version)  and [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/340705/when-should-dependencies-be-updated) , but I do it currently, because as I said , I love upgrading stuff.

The question is , when I update only the dependencies of a project, e.g. (`npm update`) how should I change the SemVer versioning ? The updated packages does not add new features automatically to the business logic,so I believe no `major increase` and just `increasing the patch` ? On the other hand they make the program compatible with newer components or engines, and sometimes they fix bugs, so a `minor increase` ?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you that keeping dependencies up to date is a good idea, even though you are risking an otherwise needless release.

I would simply update the build/patch number unless your code is a component released to the public; in which case the compatibility with other projects using your dependencies comes into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I would never release a version that changes nothing in your own code *at all*. If the third-part code improves so as to satisfy a requirement that was previously unmet, then the update fixes a defect, and that's enough for a minor increase. If it doesn't, it's pure navel-gazing (and might be a pain in the ass for people who can't easily upgrade requirements because they're on a platform without internet access).